# How to bubble up a click event from a custom component in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a custom component `<item>` which looks like this:

**item.vue**

```
<script>
  export default {
    render: function (c) {
      var self = this;
      const contentEl = c('div', {staticClass:'item-content', domProps: {innerHTML: self.content}});
      return c('div', {
        staticClass: 'item',
        class: {
          'item-left': self.side === 'left',
          'item-right': self.side === 'right'
        }
      }, [contentEl])
    },
    props: {
      content: String,
    }
  }
</script>
```

It can be used like this:

```
<item :content="Hello world"></item>
```

This will print "Hello world" and works fine but now I want the item to be clickable like this:

```
<item v-on:click="myClickEvent" :content="Hello world"></item>
```

**Question:**

How can I make the `<item>` component to fire a click event when its inner `<div>` was clicked?

Comment: I finally got your issue, made a couple of edits... should be fine now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  <template>
    <div id="action-button">
      <input type="button" id="in" @click="clicked" :value="value" />    
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'action-button',
    props: {
      'value': String
    },
    methods: {
      clicked () {
        this.$emit('action-button-clicked')
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

And then instead of `v-on:click` you should use `v-on:action-button-clicked="handleClick"`.

`<action-button v-on:action-button-clicked="handleClick"></action-button>`

So the general idea is to handle clicks internally and then use `emit` inside your component.

Comment: You can read more here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Comment: @Timo I'm glad I could help. Please upvote the answer as well :)

Comment: shorthand: `<button @click="$emit('click')"></button>` parent: `<CuttomButton @click="myFn"/>`

Answer (score 10):

In the child component:

```
<button @click="$emit('click')"></button>
```

And then in the parent component:

```
<MyButton @click="someFunction"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the child component you can simply do it as [@Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58841205/6904888) said.

```
<button @click="$emit('click', $event)">My button component</button>
```

Hope it helps